# fixing maximum match algorithm while tokenizing a low resouce languge using ntlk

Tags: python, nltk

I am working to tokenize a low resource language, but while running the programme I am getting a return outside error.
 here is the code:

```
D = ['چھی', 'معلومات', 'کا', 'بندی']


def max_match(sentence, dictionary):
    if not sentence:
        return ""
for i in range(len(sentence), -1, -1):
    first_word = sentence[:i]
    remainder = sentence[i:]
    if first_word in dictionary:
        return first_word + " " + max_match(remainder, dictionary)
    first_word = sentence[0]
    remainder = sentence[1:]
        return first_word + max_match(remainder, dictionary)

print (max_match('چھیمعلوماتکا بندی'), D)
```

The error is `SyntaxError: "return" outside function`

Comment: its a 'return' outside function error

Comment: Is the `for` loop meant to be inside the `max_match` function? It isn't.

Comment: yes, it meant to be inside

Comment: Question has nothing to do with nltk

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is simple; You've failed to put the `for` loop inside the function. Your code should be this:

```py
D = ['چھی', 'معلومات', 'کا', 'بندی']


def max_match(sentence, dictionary):
    if not sentence:
        return ""
    for i in range(len(sentence), -1, -1):
        first_word = sentence[:i]
        remainder = sentence[i:]
        if first_word in dictionary:
            return first_word + " " + max_match(remainder, dictionary)
        first_word = sentence[0]
        remainder = sentence[1:]
        return first_word + max_match(remainder, dictionary)

print(max_match('چھیمعلوماتکا بندی', D))
```

Comment: Your final `return` is wrongly put inside the `for` loop instead of after it. I can't edit it because it's too short...

Comment: @ItamarMushkin ? I can't see anything wrong - it runs on my PC

Comment: it outputs error:      print (max_match('چھیمعلوماتکا بندی'), D)
TypeError: max_match() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dictionary'

Comment: @NamHadi fixed - sorry for the typo. Autocorrect put the bracket in the wrong place.

Comment: @Legorooj can you tell how the output looked like?

Comment: @NamHadi the output is as follows: `چھیمعلوماتکا بندی `